# It shows the desktop version. I want to show mobile version(now it is ok)

Tags: javascript, java, android

I tried lots of things about it from the previous same questions but I can not solve my problem. Thanks for helping!!(writing for more detail error........................................)

```js
package com.klasspor.klasspor;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.klasspor.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the page at http://www.klasspor.com is mobile compatible ?? Have you tried opening them in mobile browser ? Do they show mobile pages ?? Are you using JQuery mobile or twitter boots strap or any other javascript library ??

Comment: Try loading http://m.klasspor.com/